# Why are these values set to default with explicit constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have an `Animal` class that looks like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public bool isQuadruped;
}
```

Now if I create an object based on this class:

```
Animal Dog = new Animal();
```

I read that the compiler goes ahead and creates a default constructor, something like

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public bool isQuadruped;

    public Animal()
    {
        name = null;
        age = 0;
        isQuadruped = false;
    }
}
```

and sets the members to some default values (`strings` to `null`, `integers` to `0`, `booleans` to `false` etc.)

When I explicitly declare this constructor:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public bool isQuadruped;

    public Animal() { }
}
```

.. what exactly happens behind the scenes? Does the compiler look in the constructor and it sees nothing and it sets all the object members to the defaults? Doesn't this mean the compiler is still providing us with their own version of a constructor?

Edit:

According to @Johnathan Barclay the fields are initialised before the constructor is called, so basically the implicit constructor in this case only allows the creation of the object?

Answer (score 4):

The default constructor you assume isn't correct.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) on fields:

> Fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the object instance is called. If the constructor assigns the value of a field, it will overwrite any value given during field declaration.

Whilst a default constructor is created if one is not declared explicitly, it does not assign any field values.

Furthermore, from the [C# specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables?source=recommendations#9232-instance-variables-in-classes):

> The initial value of an instance variable of a class is the default value (§9.3) of the variable’s type.

Which explains how fields are initialised in the absence of any explicit constructor or inline assignment.

Comment: So what exactly would be the role of the implicit constructor in this case? Just allowing the creation of the object?

Comment: A constructor needs to be invoked when an object is instantiated; that's just the way that the language has been designed. The implicit constructor serves no other purpose (other than possibly calling `: base()` when inheriting from a class with a parameterless constructor).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't explicitly assign a value to your properties/fields, they will assume the default for their declared type. This is true regardless of whether or not you declare a constructor.

Here are the defaults for C# value types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values

Answer (score 1):

If you have no constructor at all (your first example), the compiler creates a default constructor behind the scenes with no parameters, which is empty.

The assignment of default values is the field initialization step, which happens before the constructor as far as i know, means:
When you enter the first line of the constructor, all fields already have their type default assigned.

```
public class Something 
{
    int somevalue;

    public Something() 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(somevalue); // Will output 0
    }
}
```