# What does the implicit constructor do in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

In case we do not declare a constructor the compiler creates one for us - the **implicit constructor**.

What exactly is it's role? I always thought the **implicit constructor** initializes the instance's members to some default values (eg. `strings` to `null`, `integers` to `0`, `booleans` to `false`)

But according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

> Fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the
> object instance is called. If the constructor assigns the value of a
> field, it will overwrite any value given during field declaration.

So, what exactly is the purpose of the **implicit constructor**? Just a behind the scenes mechanism that facilitates the creation of an instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, what exactly is the purpose of the implicit constructor? Just a behind the scenes mechanism that facilitates the creation of an instance?

Yes. Its (only) purpose is to allow you to write `var x = new MyObject()` without having to create an empty public¹ constructor `public MyObject() : base() { }` first.

The official name of what you call an "implicit constructor" is **default instance constructor**, and it is described in detail in section 14.11.5 of the C# specification:

- [14.11.5 Default constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#14115-default-constructors)

---

¹ The default constructor has a visibility of `public`, unless the class is `abstract`, in which case the default constructor is `protected`.

Comment: If the type has any initializers on any non-static members, there's also (compiler generated) code that has to be inserted into every constructor, that one included

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's not correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016442/why-are-these-values-set-to-default-with-explicit-constructor/74016555#74016555

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - if I have `public int foo = 42` as a member of the type, where do *you* think that value gets assigned?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Before the constructor is invoked, as stated in the docs, and proven [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pLsFXQ).

Comment: That just proves that user-written code executes after the compiler generated code. If you look in the IL, there's one constructor method that first assigns 1 to that field in your example.

Comment: So the more correct answer is that the default ctor is a "container" method where the compiler can weave instance member initialization code into.

Comment: But one might argue that this could very well only be true for the dotnet implementation of the C# specification. One could imagine a compiler and runtime that work differently while still obeying the spec.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK, but that's IL, not C#. From a C# perspective, the documentation explicitly states that "fields are initialized immediately before the constructor for the object instance is called".

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride: *"So the more correct answer is that the default ctor is a "container" method where the compiler can weave instance member initialization code into."* Not just the default ctor, every ctor. That's why I (intentionally) did not mention that detail in my answer, since it's not relevant for the comparison between the default ctor and a manual ctor.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - I was talking about code the compiler injects. Of course that's into IL - that's what the compiler *emits*, not C#.